# syntax highlighting colors in php code with visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use Visual Studio Code to edit php documents.
There is CSS code inside them and I can't see the colors of the CSS.
For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento PHP</title>
<style>
    h1{
        text-align:center;
    }

    table{
        background-color:#FFC;
        padding:5px;
        border:#666 5px solid;
    }
```

How can I see the color in background-color:#FFC; inside Visual Studio Code?.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking to hover over the #FFC and see it's color in a color picker, or are you unable to see the syntax highlight of the CSS inside a php marked file?

Comment: Hi @Chris,
I want to hover over the #FFC and see it's color.
Sorry, I explained it very badly.

Comment: oh thanks for the verification, please see my updated post, just under the image. It should do what you need!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to see syntax highlighting inside of visual studio code when using CSS and HTML inside files marked PHP you can use a plugin to change the default styling. I personally use: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ecmel.vscode-html-css

[image]

In order to also have the colors show inside vs code's view you can download the following extension: 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify 
You will have to configure your settings press `CTRL + ,` to open the User Settings page and add the following config options to the right side:

```
"beautify.language": {
    "js": {
        "type": [
            "javascript",
            "json",
            "jsonc"
        ],
        "filename": [
            ".jshintrc",
            ".jsbeautifyrc"
        ]
    },
    "css": [
        "css",
        "scss",
        "php"
    ],
    "html": [
        "htm",
        "html",
        "php"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Dear Chris, I kindly ask you the opposite. I have this `<a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL ?>">Home</a></li>` and both `echo` and the constant  `ROOT_URL` are colored almost white. How do I change their color? Thank you